# button is not aligned with other component in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, styles

How to align the `button` along with other `component`. means button should be on same line. it is above other components.

[image]

```html
<div className="row mb-12">
  <div className="col-md-3">
    <label htmlFor="noOfSubjects">No Of Subjects</label>
    <Field className="form-control" name="noOfSubjects" type="number" placeholder="Enter the number of subjects" />
    <p className="text-danger">
      <ErrorMessage name="noOfSubjects" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <div className="col-md-3">
    <label htmlFor="startDate">Start Date</label>
    <Field id="startDate" type="date" name="startDate" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Start Date" />
    <p className="text-danger">
      <ErrorMessage name="startDate" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <div className="col-md-3">
    <label htmlFor="endDate">End Date</label>
    <Field id="endDate" type="date" name="endDate" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter the End Date" />
    <p className="text-danger">
      <ErrorMessage name="endDate" />
    </p>
  </div>

  <div className="col-md-3">
    <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block offset-md-3" type="submit">Search Certificate</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

which `class` property I need to set to make it in same line?

Comment: You can try to put `pt-1` or `pt-2` on the `div` above `button`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple just add class to row "align-items-center"

```
  <div class="row align-items-center mb-12">

  ....

 </div>
```